# iOS 7 webview not working

Tags: ios, ios7, uiwebview

when i build my apps with one page the code works fine, but when i use more than one view the app will not display the webpage, evan tough i am using identical code

in view controller.h i have this code

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
IBOutlet UIWebView *webview;
}

@end
```

in view controlled.m i have this code

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL      URLWithString:@"http://www.twitter.com/GeekyLemon"]]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

now this code works fine and is the same in the other project yet the one with multiple views won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked these points :

- have you set the controller as a WebViewDelegate ?
- Did you linked the webview from storyboard to your IBOutlet in controller ?
- When you're debugging, is the instance of your webview different from nil ?

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to fix your issue without a detailed description, but try to add this method into .m file. :

```
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];


    [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL      URLWithString:@"http://www.twitter.com/GeekyLemon"]]];
}
```

and from `viewDidLoad` remove this line : `[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL      URLWithString:@"http://www.twitter.com/GeekyLemon"]]];`

`viewDidLoad` is invoking only once I suppose that this issue apper when you go to other ViewController and then go back.